# Como excluir ítens em uma matriz? (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, lista, matriz

Eu preciso construir um programa onde o usuário poderá que excluir os eventos da programação de eventos, mas o problema aqui é que quando ele exclui mais outro evento,digo, depois de ter excluído o primeiro (uma sublista/matriz inteira, pelo número indicado ali no ao lado do nome), a posição dos componentes dentro da matriz mudam de posição e fazem com que seja excluído o componente errado, que o usuário não digitou...Coloquei apenas 2 matrizes aqui para mostrar, mas no programa há bem mais delas.

```
 cienciatec = [['1-Nome do evento: Introdução a Data Science', 'Categoria: Palestra', 'Dia: Terça-feira', 'Horário: 9:00', 'Local: Sala 01', 'Número de vagas: 20', 'Informações: -'],['2-Nome do evento: Educação Inclusiva e o planejamento didático-pedagógico', 'Categoria: Palestra', 'Dia: Terça-feira', 'Horário: 9:00', 'Local: Sala 02', 'Número de vagas: 20']]
    while resp == 'A' or resp == 'E':
    if resp == 'E':
     print('Tecle o número correspondente ao evento que deseja excluir')
     exclui = int(input())
     cienciatec.pop(exclui-1)
    #imprime os dados do evento pulando linha
     for c in range(len(cienciatec)):
       for i in range(len(cienciatec[c])):
           print(cienciatec[c][i])
     #resto do programa
     print('Deseja efetuar alguma tarefa?')
     resp = input()
```

Answer (score 2):

Posso sugerir que você não trabalhe dessa forma?

Você claramente precisa de um array associativo para esse programa, os chamados `dicionários` em Python. Dessa forma, ao invés de associar o nome do evento, ou o tipo do evento a uma posição arbitrária da lista, você pode associá-la a "nome", ou "tipo".

Exemplo:

```
cienciatec = [{
    'Número do evento': 1,
    'Nome do evento': 'Introdução a Data Science', 
    'Categoria': 'Palestra', 
    'Dia': 'Terça-feira', 
    'Horário': '9:00', 
    'Local': 'Sala 01', 
    'Número de vagas': 20, 
    'Informações': '-'
},{
    'Número do evento': 2,
    'Nome do evento': 'Educação Inclusiva e o planejamento didático-pedagógico', 
    'Categoria': 'Palestra', 
    'Dia': 'Terça-feira', 
    'Horário': '9:00', 
    'Local': 'Sala 02', 
    'Número de vagas': 20,
    'Informações': '-'
}]
```

Dessa forma você pode acessar o valor de nome com `cienciatec[0]['Nome do evento']`, `cienciatec[1]['Nome do evento']`...

Você também pode iterar sobre dicionários com `for`

```
for evento in cienciatec:
    for i in evento:
        print(f'{i}: {evento[i]}')
    print('------')
```

---

Agora quanto a solução do problema. Ao invés de deletar uma posição específica na lista, utilize o número digitado pelo usuário para pesquisar pela correspondência na lista e remove-la.

```
 print('Tecle o número correspondente ao evento que deseja excluir')
 numero = int(input())

 #Procuro pelo dicionário que contém o índice "Número do evento" igual ao digitado pelo usuário
 a_excluir = next(evento for evento in cienciatec if evento["Número do evento"] == numero)
 cienciatec.remove(a_excluir)
```